# Pattern matcher results in alphabetical order

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm using the [java class Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to filter a search `query`. I would like the returned items to be in alphanumeric order -- i.e. A-Z0-9, case insensitive. How can I implement this into the code below? Yes it's Android but it's all Java :) The filter works, I just need to put the `pattern` results in order! Thanks in advance.

Here the filter is defined:

```
@Override
public android.widget.Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter(
            new AnonListAdapter.Predicate<InstanceAnonChartData, CharSequence>() {
                public boolean test(InstanceAnonChartData instance,
                        CharSequence constraint) {
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        String query = constraint.toString();
                        if (query.isEmpty())
                            return true;

                        // Matches any word starting with the given string
                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i-m)(^|\\W)" + query);

                        // Check if the pattern matches either the symbol or the name
                        return pattern.matcher(instance.getName()).find() ||
                                pattern.matcher(instance.getSymbol()).find();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
}
```

Here the filter is implemented:

```
public void applyFilter(CharSequence query) {
    if (_listAdapter != null && query != null) {
        Filter listFilter = _listAdapter.getFilter();
        if (listFilter != null) {
            listFilter.filter(query);
        }
    }
}
...
private void handleIntent(@NonNull Intent intent) {
    // Handle "Search" intents
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // SearchManager.QUERY is the key that a SearchManager will use to send a query string
        // to an Activity.
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        _listFragment.applyFilter(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "alphabetical order"... The problem is that this may, or may not, be the same as `String`'s canonical order (which only relies on `char` values); if you are looking to compare strings in a language specific manner, then you need to use a `Collator`.

Comment: The filter just takes strings one at a time, in whatever order the caller tells it to, and returns `true` or `false for each string.  The filter is not the right place to try to put results in order.  That will have to be done by whoever collects the strings that get through the filter.  In other words, you _cannot_ implement it in the code you've shown us.  It will have to be done somewhere else.

Comment: @ajb thank you, so then I think the ordering should be done where the filter is implemented -- in `applyFilter()` or `handleIntent()`. I've added those methods above. Please take a look!

Comment: Please, share your `Filter` code. Why is it taking an instance of `AnonListAdapter.Predicate`? And where's the implementation for `performFiltering()` and `publishResults()`?

Comment: No, I think you still don't get it.  The code that does the ordering has to have an array or list or some other kind of collection, that contains *all* the strings that need to be ordered.  None of the code I'm looking at has more than one string available to it.  So how can any of that code be fixed to put the strings in order?  Maybe I don't understand your code--it's not really clear what you're doing.